# How to access an excel column inside a function, inside a loop?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am trying to build a flow which:

1. Receives a date/time from Excel (in ISO 8601 format)
2. Calculates this as a number of hours and minutes
3. Formats this for an email to be sent

The data in Excel is the amount of hours a staff member has worked in the week. The data is received in Power Automate as:

[image: ravenair_cfi_0-1651666106532.png]

The flow is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Currently, the flow gives "duty24Hours" and "referenceZero" the same ticks value, and therefore the email always sends "0" as the hours worked. I have concluded that "duty24Hours" is not reading the value from the ABC excel method, and is defaulting to 0.

Please can someone assist?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The excel workbook where the data is stored contains a sheet for each staff member. Each sheet has a table which a separate flow inserts into. This then totals in grey table on the right, which is the data that the flow in question reads.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot (preferably one with a better resolution than the ones you currently have in your question) of the Excel sheet where the values are?

Comment: @Skin done, with (hopefully) better screenshots throughout